# ncurses can't find any documentation on cchar_t

Tags: c++, c, unicode, ncurses

I am trying to read a char from my ncurses terminal with mvin_wch() which returns a cchar_t, I know this is a struct with stuff like color information and a wchar_t. I can't seem to find any information about this cchar_t. I just wan't to know what it's members are named. I don't get why such an important part of the ncursesw library isn't documented anywhere.

Comment: I think you're supposed to use `getcchar()` and `setcchar()` to access the information the `cchar_t` type holds.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html

Answer (score 7):

If you ***have*** to know, read **`curses.h`**, but as noted, you are expected to manipulate **`cchar_t`** using the library calls, e.g., [setcchar](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getcchar.3x.html#h3-setcchar) and [getcchar](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getcchar.3x.html#h3-getcchar).  Each implementation of curses uses different details for this structure.  The [ncurses manual page](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Datatypes) tells all that you need to know about its content:

```
           cchar_t
                corresponds to chtype.  However it is a structure, because
                more data is stored than can fit  into  an  integer.   The
                characters  are  large  enough  to  require a full integer
                value - and there may be more than one character per cell.
                The  video  attributes  and  color  are stored in separate
                fields of the structure.

                Each cell (row and column) in a  WINDOW  is  stored  as  a
                cchar_t.
```

For the video attributes, pay attention to the [*PORTABILITY*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html#h2-PORTABILITY) section of the attributes manual page.

In the comments, one pointed to X/Open Curses page on [datatypes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/curses.h.html).  The description of `cchar_t` therein is inaccurate:

> **`cchar_t`**
>   References a string of wide characters

(it is not a reference to a string, but a complete "wide" character in itself).