# How do I print Unicode characters using ncurses in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, ncurses

I am making a chess game on the C++ console and I can't seem to be able to output the Unicode symbols for the chess pieces.

```
#define whiteking 0x2654
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    wchar_t c = whiteking;
    add_wch(c);
    getch();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

The error returned is:

```
In file included from main.cpp:4:0:
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:624:5: error: invalid conversion from ‘wchar_t’ to ‘const cchar_t*’ 
[-fpermissive]
 add_wch(c);
 ^
/usr/include/ncursesw/curses.h:1703:28: note:   initializing argument 2 of 
‘int wadd_wch(WINDOW*, const cchar_t*)’
 extern NCURSES_EXPORT(int) wadd_wch (WINDOW *,const cchar_t *);  /* 
implemented */
```

The includes are:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <ncursesw/ncurses.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

None of the other stack overflow answers seems to help me. I am using [this online compiler](http://www.onlinegdb.com). Thank you for your help!

Comment: onlinegdb might just not support unicode, you might have more luck printing utf-8

Comment: But it can with wprintf, while not using ncurses. https://onlinegdb.com/B142G3Pow

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52248708/4386278

Comment: I don't get it. I am a beginner. Please explain

Answer (score 1):

X/Open Curses (ncurses) uses a variety of datatypes.  [`cchar_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248221/ncurses-cant-find-any-documentation-on-cchar-t/52248708#52248708) is a structure, while `wchar_t` is not.

You can do what was intended using a different function:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>

#define whiteking 0x2654
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    wchar_t s[2];
    s[0] = whiteking;
    s[1] = 0;
    addwstr(s);
    getch();

    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```