ncurses cannot display wide characters with colour
attempting to print a unicode character. It does not work.
Here is my code:
#include <locale.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        initscr();
        noecho();
        start_color();
        init_pair(0x26, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
        mvwaddch(stdscr, 0, 0, L'\u263A');

        getch();

        endwin();

        return 0;
}

compiled with clang -lncursesw main.c
expected output: white "☺"
actual output: blue ":"

chtype uses 8-bit chars because curses is ancient. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52248221/1216776

You are missing a couple of important things.

For wide output, use UTF-8 strings. It’ll work fine.
Don’t forget to apply the color attribute you wish to use.
Smileys are a special class of Unicode character.
You might have to colorize them using a color modifying code point.

This works as you expect:
#include <locale.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
        initscr();
        noecho();
        start_color();
        init_pair(0x26, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK); // initialize the pair
        attrset(COLOR_PAIR(0x26)); // use the pair
        mvaddstr(0, 0, "\u263A");

        getch();

        endwin();

        return 0;
}

BTW, it is kind of notably odd that you are using 0x26 as your color pair number. On modern terminals you probably have 64 or 256 color pairs to mess with, but you should definitely check that at the beginning of your program, and design your program to colorize itself appropriately. You can safely limit yourself to having 2, 16, 64, and 256 possible color pairs. This, alas, part of the pain of using colors in the terminal: Require your users to use a modern terminal emulator like Gnome Terminal or something.
P.S. It is totally worth your time looking through https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html and https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/ .

this prints '~X '

the 0x26 was because 0x263A starts with 0x26 and it makes the program interpret the 0x263A as the colour 0x26 and the char 0x3A
