# creating borders in ncurses with unicode characters

Tags: c++, ncurses

Currently coding in C++ in WSL2 with ncursesw.

For the `box()` or `border()` functions/macros in ncurses, is it possible to use unicode characters with them, or do they not fit in the category of `chtype`?

I'm trying to create a border using the double line box drawing characters.

If not, do I have to create a border manually with other functions such as `addstr()` in for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`box`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_border.3x.html) and **`border`** use ***`chtype`***'s which provide only [**`A_CHARTEXT`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html#h2-VIDEO-ATTRIBUTES) bits for characters (8 bits in ncurses).  To go beyond that, use [**`box_set`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_border_set.3x.html) and **`border_set`**.  Those use ***`cchar_t`*** structures, which you would initialize with [**`setcchar`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getcchar.3x.html#h3-setcchar).